# C++ reading inputs from dice access violations

Tags: c++

```
  #include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


    char img[30][15];
    char x = 'X';
    int dotLoc[24][2];
    int dotNum = 0;
    int ret[4];
    int curDie = 0;
    int dieNum = 0;
    int der = 0;

    vector<int>* readDice(vector<string>&);
    int dieDots(int, int);
    void findDots();
    bool adjX(int,int);
    bool traverse(int,int,int,int);


vector<int>* readDice(vector<string>& anImage) {
  // TODO: implement method



    vector<int> result;
    //blank initialization
    for (int poop = 0; poop < 4 ; poop ++){
        ret[poop] = -1;
    }
    //blank initialization
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 24 ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 2 ; j++){
            dotLoc[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
    //blank initialization
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 30 ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 15 ; j++){
            img[i][j] = '.';
        }
    }
    //blank initialization
    dotNum = 0;
    curDie = 0;
    dieNum = 0;
    der = 0;


    // original to char array
    for(int i = 0 ; i < anImage.size() ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < anImage[i].size() ; j++){
            img[i][j] = anImage.at(i)[j];
        }
    }

    // initialize dotLoc to -1
    for(int j = 0; j < 24 ; j++){
        dotLoc[j][0] = -1;
        dotLoc[j][1] = -1;
    }
    findDots();

    for(int p = 0; p < 4 ; p++){
        for(int j = 0; j < 24 ; j++){
            if(!(dotLoc[j][0] == -1)){
                der = j;
                ret[p] = dieDots(dotLoc[j][0],dotLoc[j][1]);
            }
        }
    }

    for (int poop = 0; poop < 4 ; poop ++){
        if (!(ret[poop] == -1)){
            result.push_back(ret[poop]);
        }
    }


    return &result;
}

int dieDots(int x, int y){
    curDie = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < 24 ; j++){

            if(!(dotLoc[j][0] == -1)){
                if(traverse(x,y,dotLoc[j][0],dotLoc[j][1])){
                    curDie++;
                    dotLoc[j][0] = -1;
                    dotLoc[j][1] = -1;
                }
            }

    }
    dotLoc[der][0] = -1;
    dotLoc[der][1] = -1;

    return curDie;
}

void findDots(){
    for(int i = 0; i <30 ; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j <15 ; j++){
            if(img[i][j] == x){
                if (!adjX(i,j)){
                    dotLoc[dotNum][0] = i;
                    dotLoc[dotNum][1] = j;
                    dotNum++;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

bool adjX(int a, int b){    
    if ( (img[a-1][b]) == x || (img[a][b-1]) == x ){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

// True if same die
bool traverse(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2){
    if((x1 == x2) && (y1 == y2)){
        return true;
    }
    if(img[x2][y2] == '.'){
        return false;
    }

    int dX = x1-x2;
    int dY = y1-y2;
    bool lol;
    if(dX > dY){
        lol = traverse(x1, y1, x1+dX-1, y1+dY);
        if (lol){
            return true;
        }
    }
    else{
        lol = traverse(x1, y1, x1+dX, y1+dY-1);
        if (lol){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

int main (int argc, char * const argv[]) {
    cout << "testing C++ readDice method..." << endl;

    vector<string> input;
    vector<int>    expected;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        input   .clear();
        expected.clear();
        switch (i) {
            case 0:
                input   .push_back( "***...***.***.." );
                input   .push_back( "*X*..*X*...*X*." );
                input   .push_back( "***.***.....***" );
                expected.push_back( 1 );
                expected.push_back( 1 );
                expected.push_back( 1 );
                break;
            case 1:
                input   .push_back( "****..****" );
                input   .push_back( "*X**..XX**" );
                input   .push_back( "**X*..**XX" );
                input   .push_back( "****..****" );
                expected.push_back( 2 );
                expected.push_back( 2 );
                break;
            case 2:
                input   .push_back( ".***..X**..X*X." );
                input   .push_back( ".*X*..*X*..*X*." );
                input   .push_back( ".***..**X..X*X." );
                expected.push_back( 1 );
                expected.push_back( 3 );
                expected.push_back( 5 );
                break;
            case 3:
                input   .push_back( "*X*X*.*****......" );
                input   .push_back( "*****.*X*X*.**X**" );
                input   .push_back( "*X*X*.**X**.*X*X*" );
                input   .push_back( "*****.*X*X*.**X**" );
                input   .push_back( "*X*X*.*****......" );
                expected.push_back( 4 );
                expected.push_back( 5 );
                expected.push_back( 6 );
                break;
            case 4:
                input   .push_back( ".............................." );
                input   .push_back( ".............................." );
                input   .push_back( "...............*.............." );
                input   .push_back( "...*****......****............" );
                input   .push_back( "...*X***.....**X***..........." );
                input   .push_back( "...*****....***X**............" );
                input   .push_back( "...***X*.....****............." );
                input   .push_back( "...*****.......*.............." );
                input   .push_back( ".............................." );
                input   .push_back( "........***........******....." );
                input   .push_back( ".......**X****.....*X**X*....." );
                input   .push_back( "......*******......******....." );
                input   .push_back( ".....****X**.......*X**X*....." );
                input   .push_back( "........***........******....." );
                input   .push_back( ".............................." );
                expected.push_back( 1 );
                expected.push_back( 2 );
                expected.push_back( 2 );
                expected.push_back( 4 );
                break;
            case 5:
                input   .push_back( ".................******..." );
                input   .push_back( "....*.............**X***.." );
                input   .push_back( "...*X*.............***X**." );
                input   .push_back( ".******.............******" );
                input   .push_back( "*X*XX*X*.................." );
                input   .push_back( ".******.*****.......******" );
                input   .push_back( "..*X*...***X*......**XX**." );
                input   .push_back( "...*....**X**.....**XX**.." );
                input   .push_back( "........*X***....******..." );
                input   .push_back( "........*****............." );
                expected.push_back( 1 );
                expected.push_back( 2 );
                expected.push_back( 3 );
                expected.push_back( 5 );
                break;
            case 6:
                input   .push_back( "......*............." );
                input   .push_back( ".....*X**..........." );
                input   .push_back( "....****X*.........." );
                input   .push_back( "...*X****.....******" );
                input   .push_back( "....**X*.....**X***." );
                input   .push_back( "......*.....***X**.." );
                input   .push_back( "...........******..." );
                input   .push_back( "........***........." );
                input   .push_back( ".......****X**......" );
                input   .push_back( "......**XX***......." );
                input   .push_back( ".....*X*****........" );
                input   .push_back( "........***........." );
                expected.push_back( 1 );
                expected.push_back( 3 );
                expected.push_back( 4 );
                break;
            case 7:
                input   .push_back( "............................" );
                input   .push_back( ".......**..................." );
                input   .push_back( "......**X**.........**......" );
                input   .push_back( ".....*X***X*......*X***....." );
                input   .push_back( "......**X**......***X***...." );
                input   .push_back( "........**...**...***X*....." );
                input   .push_back( "...**.......*X*X*...**......" );
                input   .push_back( ".**X**.....***X***.........." );
                input   .push_back( "***X***.....*X*X*..........." );
                input   .push_back( ".**X**........**............" );
                input   .push_back( "..**........................" );
                input   .push_back( "............................" );
                expected.push_back( 1 );
                expected.push_back( 3 );
                expected.push_back( 4 );
                expected.push_back( 5 );
                break;
            case 8:
                input   .push_back( "......*............." );
                input   .push_back( ".....*X**..........." );
                input   .push_back( "....*X**X*.........." );
                input   .push_back( "...*X**X*.....******" );
                input   .push_back( "....**X*.....X*X*X*." );
                input   .push_back( "......*.....X*X*X*.." );
                input   .push_back( "...........******..." );
                input   .push_back( "....***............." );
                input   .push_back( "...**X*X**.**X*X**.." );
                input   .push_back( "..**X*X**...**X*X**." );
                input   .push_back( ".*X**X**.....**X**X*" );
                input   .push_back( "....***............." );
                expected.push_back( 6 );
                expected.push_back( 6 );
                expected.push_back( 6 );
                expected.push_back( 6 );
                break;
            case 9:
                input   .push_back( "..........*****" );
                input   .push_back( "..**......**X**" );
                input   .push_back( ".*XX*.....*****" );
                input   .push_back( "*****.........." );
                input   .push_back( "*XX*...X**....." );
                input   .push_back( ".**...**X**...." );
                input   .push_back( ".....XX**XX*..." );
                input   .push_back( "......*X***...." );
                input   .push_back( ".......*X*....." );
                expected.push_back( 1 );
                expected.push_back( 2 );
                expected.push_back( 6 );
                break;
            default:
                cout << "should not reach here!" << endl;
                break;
        }
        vector<int>* actual = readDice( input );
        bool         ok     = expected == *actual;
        cout << "test " << i << ": " << (ok ? "ok" : "failed") << endl;

        delete actual;
    }
    cout << "done!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

It gives me a runtime error of "Unhandled exception at 0x5b9fad4a (msvcp100d.dll) in painis.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xccccccd0."

Also, it creates another file called xutility and stops at this point
C++ Syntax (Toggle Plain Text)

```
    for (_Iterator_base12 **_Pnext = &_Myproxy->_Myfirstiter;
        *_Pnext != 0; *_Pnext = (*_Pnext)->_Mynextiter)
        (*_Pnext)->_Myproxy = 0;
    _Myproxy->_Myfirstiter = 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please put a little more effort in your questions and check out the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). This will show that you have tried on your own. What you posted does not help in determining what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 3):

`readDice` is returning the address of a local variable — classic [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (see also:
[dangling references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_pointer)).